# Home links redirects to old site

Tags: htaccess

So I have a issue that can´t really wrap my head around, it is most likely .htaccess related. I have just moved my site from a subdirectory to the main directory, this was done changing the site url and the url of the sitebuilder. The new site works fine, but the links to example.se redirects to http://example.se/www.example.se/Valkommen.html, this is the way the old site was set up. Now I wonder how to stop this from happening, where I unfortunately removed the old site including its htaccess file.

Comment: What about all other urls like page and post url?

Comment: all the other links to posts, images, pages and custom post types work fine. Even the example.se/en link works. It is just the home url (example.se) that redirects to http://example.se/www.example.se/Valkommen.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First back up your database. It is always wise to do that before doing anything. Now download and install Velvet Blues Update URLs plugin. Enter your old URL (like http://example.se/www.example.se) and new URL (like http://www.example.com) and select all options and click Update. Also update your permalinks afterward.  This should sort your problem